# Polymorphic reference with single table inheritance in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am new to sqlalchemy and trying to figure out how this should work.

I have two objects.  Here in MWE (obviously they have more attributes and methods than this):

```py
class Block:
    parts: Union[Block, Line]
    title: str

class Line:
    content: str
    title: str
```

I'm trying to persist these in sql with sqlalchemy, but I can't work out how to persist the `parts` relationship.  Here is my attempt, but it doesn't create any references (the child_id column is always null):

```py
from sqlalchemy import Column, ForeignKey, Integer, String, create_engine
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session, relationship

Base = declarative_base()


class Things(Base):
    __tablename__ = "things"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    type = Column(String)
    __mapper_args__ = {"polymorphic_on": type, "polymorphic_identity": "thing"}


class Assoc(Base):
    __tablename__ = "assoc"
    parent_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("things.id"), primary_key=True)
    child_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("things.id"), primary_key=True, nullable=True)


class Block(Things):
    __mapper_args__ = {"polymorphic_identity": "block"}
    title = Column(String)
    parts = relationship("Things", secondary="assoc", foreign_keys=[Assoc.parent_id])


class Line(Things):
    content = Column(String, index=True)
    __mapper_args__ = {"polymorphic_identity": "line"}


engine = create_engine("sqlite://", echo=False)
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

session = Session(engine)

b = Block(title="block1", parts=[Block(title="subBlock 1"), Line(content="line1")])
l = Line(content="line2")
b.parts
b.parts.append(l)
b.parts
session.add(b)
session.commit()

session = Session(engine)

b = Block(title="block1", parts=[Block(title="subBlock 1"), Line(content="line1")])
l = Line(content="line2")
b.parts.append(l)
print("Before commit block1 parts:", [type(x).__name__ for x in b.parts])
print("Before commit block1 subBlock:", [x.title for x in b.parts if type(x) is Block])
session.add(b)
session.commit()

for i in session.query(Block):
    print(f"obj {i.title} in db parts:", [x.title for x in i.parts])

for i in session.query(Line):
    print("line in db:", i.content)
for i in session.query(Assoc):
    print(i.parent_id, i.child_id)
```

This yields:

```py
Before commit block1 parts: ['Block', 'Line', 'Line']
Before commit block1 subBlock: ['subBlock 1']
obj block1 in db parts: []
obj subBlock 1 in db parts: ['subBlock 1']
line in db: line1
line in db: line2
2 None
3 None
4 None
```

What am I doing wrong?  How do I reference *either lines or blocks* in `parts`?

(I don't really care about using single table inheritance, it just looked easier to reference 'any object in the parent table' this way.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright I think I've figured it out. I would appreciate criticism of the approach: I've no experience with sqlalchemy.

MWE:

```py
from sqlalchemy import Column, ForeignKey, Integer, String, create_engine
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session, relationship

Base = declarative_base()


class Things(Base):
    __tablename__ = "things"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    type = Column(String)
    __mapper_args__ = {"polymorphic_on": type, "polymorphic_identity": "thing"}


class Assoc(Base):
    __tablename__ = "assoc"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    parent_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("things.id"))
    child_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("things.id"))


class Block(Things):
    __mapper_args__ = {"polymorphic_identity": "block"}
    title = Column(String)
    parts = relationship(
        "Things",
        secondary="assoc",
        primaryjoin=Things.id == Assoc.parent_id,
        secondaryjoin=Things.id == Assoc.child_id,
    )

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Block {self.title} with parts {[repr(x) for x in self.parts]}"


class Line(Things):
    content = Column(String, index=True)
    __mapper_args__ = {"polymorphic_identity": "line"}

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Line with content {self.content}"


engine = create_engine("sqlite://", echo=False)
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

session = Session(engine)


b = Block(title="block1", parts=[Block(title="subBlock 1"), Line(content="line1")])
l = Line(content="line2")
b.parts.append(l)
print("Pre commit")
print(b)
session.add(b)
c = Block(title="block2", parts=[Line(content="line3")])
print(c)
session.add(c)

session.commit()

print("\nThings:")
for i, obj in enumerate(session.query(Things)):
    print(f"{i} :", obj)

print("\nBlocks:")
for i, obj in enumerate(session.query(Block)):
    print(f"{i} :", obj)

print("\nAssoc:")
for i in session.query(Assoc):
    print(i.parent_id, i.child_id)
```

This yields:

```py
Pre commit
Block block1 with parts ['Block subBlock 1 with parts []', 'Line with content line1', 'Line with content line2']
Block block2 with parts ['Line with content line3']

Things:
0 : Block block1 with parts ['Block subBlock 1 with parts []', 'Line with content line1', 'Line with content line2']
1 : Block subBlock 1 with parts []
2 : Line with content line1
3 : Line with content line2
4 : Block block2 with parts ['Line with content line3']
5 : Line with content line3

Blocks:
0 : Block block1 with parts ['Block subBlock 1 with parts []', 'Line with content line1', 'Line with content line2']
1 : Block subBlock 1 with parts []
2 : Block block2 with parts ['Line with content line3']

Assoc:
5 6
1 2
1 3
1 4
```

** Edit: Previous error was a silly typo.  Today is a brain mush day. **

Answer (score 0):

To do a many-to-many relationship, you have two options: Either to create an association object that connects the two tables, or to create an additional "Things" table that would be a link between the two tables. I prefer the latter because it's only this choice where you can add additional columns to store information that might be appropriate to the "Things" but not to simply your "Block" or "Line". Use the "ForeignKey" column type to reference back and forth, and you'll want to create a "Relationship" attribute so you can do a "back_populates" on the object, and then you should have a reference to it.

If you're concerned about the order of the parts, then I would recommend using a "sort_order" column (or something of a similar name) where you can store that information. That pretty much means you have to use the "Things" table, since that's where you'd store that sort of thing.

Comment: thank you! I've updated the question clarifying it and showing an attempt at a relationship which is failing.  My brain is mush today and I'm sure there's something obvious going wrong.